# wamp server localhost not working after changing the port 80 to 8085

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, wampserver

I'm trying to open my Wamp server by entering this URL into my web browser:

```
http://localhost/
```

The browser returns a **400 error**, stating that the webpage is not available.

Earlier, my Wamp server had stopped working (it was not turning green in the control panel) after I had installed `tomcat`. I found out that there was a conflict between ports with the two services, so I changed the port used by Wamp server from 80 to 8085 (8085 port is being used my tomcat).

To change the port, I the following change to the `httpd.conf` file:

```
Listen 80   //changed to 8085
ServerName localhost:8080  //changed to 8085
```

After that, the Wamp server turned green in the control panel and appeared to be working, but accessing the URL `http://localhost/` still returned the **400 error**.

What is happening?

Comment: you're putting `http://localhost:8085/` into the address bar, right?

Comment: No I wasn't... Thank you.That was the issue.

Comment: @TanyaKapoor - If you've solved the problem and one of the answers to your question helped, please mark that answer as accepted to help future visitors to SO see how to solve this same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand the difference between normal ports, web browsers, and non-standard ports. The "web" runs on port 80 by default, and 443 for secured connections. But this isn't all that a URL can do.

Per [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738), the URL can be formatted as such:

```
protocol://username:password@host.tld:port
```

Most browsers assume you mean to access the server **anonymously**, via **port 80**, and using the **HTTP protocol**.

In this case, you changed the default port that Apache would listen on to 8085. This means that you must specify the port as `8085` for the server to respond to the request.

The URL should be:

```
http://localhost:8085
```

Answer (score 0):

The httpd.conf file into the folder you listen port Apache Find veto the change now

## Listen 12.34.56.78:80

Listen any number
for sample
Listen 68